# #define to resolve namespace clashes

Tags: c#, wcf, c-preprocessor

I have several WCF services that share classes but because of the way WCF works, these classes are all seen as new and different classes.

**Question: Is there a way to use C#'s #define to nicely resolve the clashes in a more readable way?**

Can I do something like

```
#define Dog global::My_Project.DogServiceReference.Dog
```

So that I can then do

```
List <Dog> dogs = ...
```

instead of

```
List<global::My_Project.DogServiceReference.Dog>
```

Comment: Will a using alias work for this"  `using GlobalDog = global::My_Project.DogServiceReference.Dog` And then use `List<GlobalDog> dogs = ...`  I haven't tried this.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway that does it! Thanks!

Comment: @BrianTompsett this is not a C question.

Comment: @codecaster The C# preprocessor operates much as the C one does and is covered by the same tag

Comment: @Brian sure, but that's not what the tag says. Are you on a burnination quest? Then you may want to leave the meta link in your edit summary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Chris Dunaway wrote:

> Will a using alias work for this" `using GlobalDog = global::My_Project.DogServiceReference.Dog` and then use `List<GlobalDog> dogs = ...`
>   I haven't tried this.

Comment: ([Answered in a comment and converted to a community Wiki](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments)).